# OCaml: swapping elements in a list

Tags: list, ocaml

I'm wondering how can I write a function that divides a given list to sublists in a given point, swaps these sublists and returns a resulting list.

For example:

```
swap([1;3;5;6],2) => [5;6;1;3]
```

I suppose that the code that I developed is correct?

```
let rec swap (l,n) =
let rec loop t (count,laux)  =
            match t with
            |  h::t when count < n -> loop t (count+1, h::laux)
            |  h::t ->   h::t@  List.rev laux
            | []->[]
in
    loop l (0,[])
```

;;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem is your function handles the case when length of `l` is greater or equals to `n` incorrectly.

The pattern `[]` doesn't mean input list is empty; it means we come to the end of the list. What you should do at that point is returning the accumulator `acc` in the reverse order.

I rearrange patterns a little bit so base cases come first:

```
let rec swap (l, n) =
    let rec loop xs count acc =
            match xs with
            | _ when count = n -> xs @ List.rev acc
            | [] -> List.rev acc
            | h::t -> loop t (count+1) (h::acc)
     in loop l 0 []
```